# bubble sorting in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value, bubble-sort

I am trying to do **bubble sort** in descending order

```
input={"m":1,"i":4,"s":4,"P":2}

output={"i":4,"s":4,"p":2,"m":1}
```

but a type error occurs. How can I do this?

Below is the code:

```
dict={"m":1,"i":4,"s":4,"P":2}
for key,value in dict.items():
    if(dict[key]<dict[key+1]):
        temp=dict[key]
        dict[key]=dict[key+1]
        dict[key+1]=temp
print(dict)
```

Comment: Why do you use a dictionary here to keep track of the indices?

Comment: A dictionary *has* no order, so that means that you can not alter the way it represents it keys.

Comment: What's `dict[key+1]` supposed to be?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i need to sort the values in descending order

Comment: @TanyaChaudhary You can sort the values in descending order with `sorted(input.values(), reverse=True)`. The `output` you posted is not possible. (Also try to avoid overwriting names of builtins like `dict`, `input`, ...)

Comment: I am not sure about bubblesort but if you just want to sort the values, Python supports `OrderededDict`. Maybe you can look into that

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: 1. Could you post the complete traceback? 2. What exactly are you trying to do? Is this just about sorting the dictionary? 3. And if that's the case you want to order it for the `keys` or the `values`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In python 3.7+ `dict`s keep keys in insertion order (in CPython3.6 they do to as implementation detail).

Comment: @toti08 original question is to remove duplicate entries in dictionary and count the duplicate values indescending order

Comment: Ok, thanks! Then I think that @timgeb's comment gives you the proper hint on how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary has *no order*: if you add/remove/update elements in a dictionary, the order in which the keys are iterated can change.

So you can not "sort" a dictionary. What you *can* do however, is for example sort a *list of 2-tuples*, like:

```
my_list = list(my_dict.items())
```

We then retrieve:

```
>>> my_list
[('m', 1), ('i', 4), ('s', 4), ('P', 2)]
```

and thnen we can sort the *list* (for example with bubblesort) like:

```
for mx in range(len(my_list)-1, -1, -1):
    swapped = False
    for i in range(mx):
        if my_list[i][1] < my_list[i+1][1]:
            my_list[i], my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1], my_list[i]
            swapped = True
    if not swapped:
        break
```

Then afterwards, we have:

```
>>> my_list
[('i', 4), ('s', 4), ('P', 2), ('m', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```
dict={"m":1,"i":4,"s":4,"P":2}
sorted_values = sorted(dict.values(),reverse = True)
print sorted_values
```

But this isn't "manual" bubble sort. So if you have to to bubble sort this by your own just use the list of values via

```
values = dict.values()
```

And then sort them ;)

As timgeb already mentioned in a comment, I'm sorry didnt see the comment before I wrote this post.

Comment: But the OP said the original question was to count duplicate in a dictionary and count the duplicate values in descending order....

Comment: The question specifies: "*I am trying to do bubble sort in descending order*". But +1 anyway..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah thats why I wrote if he has to bubble sort the values he can start after `values = dict.values()` and then bubble sort them...

Comment: My intention was to give the OP the hint to use the `dict.values()` function.